# Tridiagonal symmetric matrix eigenvalue using bisection

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics, linear-algebra

I know that `Eigenvalues` is already quite well implemented in Mathematica, nor am I foolishly trying to improve on it. In order to improve my programming skills, I am trying to write Mathematica-style code to locate eigenvalues of a tridiagonal symmetric matrix using bisection. This is what I came up with.

```
tridiagbisec[diag_List, subdiag_List, tol_Real] := 
 Module[{diagonals = 
     Split[Transpose[{diag, Join[{0}, subdiag]}], #2[[2]] =!= 0 &]},
   Flatten[
    bisecnonzero[-myNorm[Sequence @@ Transpose[#]], 
       myNorm[Sequence @@ Transpose[#]], tol, #] & /@ diagonals]] /; 
  Length[diag] - Length[subdiag] == 1
```

`tridiagbisec` is the main function I will be calling. It builds an array (`diagonals`) from the arrays containing the matrix elements of both the leading diagonal and the subdiagonal, then `Split`s it wherever a zero is found so that each block is evaluated separately, using `bisecnonzero`.

```
bisecnonzero[λmin_Real, λmax_Real, tol_Real, diagonals_List] :=
  Module[{λmed = (λmin + λmax)/2, 
   nmin = numeig[diagonals, λmin], 
   nmax = numeig[diagonals, λmax], nmed},
  nmed = numeig[diagonals, λmed];
  {Which[(nmin > nmed) && (λmed - λmin > tol), 
    bisecnonzero[λmin, λmed, tol, diagonals],
    (nmin > nmed) && (λmed - λmin <= tol), 
    ConstantArray[(λmed + λmin)/2, nmin - nmed],
    True, {}],
   Which[(nmed > nmax) && (λmax - λmed > tol), 
    bisecnonzero[λmed, λmax, tol, diagonals],
    (nmed > nmax) && (λmax - λmed <= tol), 
    ConstantArray[(λmax + λmed)/2, nmed - nmax],
    True, {}]}
  ]
```

This, I believe, is where I may have built my program in a suboptimal way. Are two `Which` the right way to iterate bisection?

```
numeig[diagonals_, λ_] := 
  numeig[diagonals, λ] = 
   Unitize[#].UnitStep[#] & @
    Rest @ FoldList[
      If[Not @ PossibleZeroQ @ #1, #2[[
          1]] - λ - #2[[2]]^2/#1, +∞] &, 1, diagonals];
```

`numeig` computes the number of eigenvalues greater than `λ` (cfr. (5) in [Barth, Martin and Wilkinson (1967)](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/bamawi.pdf).

```
myNorm = Max[Abs@#1 + Abs@#2 + RotateLeft@Abs@#2] &;
```

I know that I am also reimplementing `Norm[#, ∞] &`, but for scholastic purposes I think it may be useful, since for a tridiagonal matrix it has a particularly simple form and this way I can avoid building a `SparseArray` structure at all.

Since I am trying to be performance-conscious, how could the whole algorithm be improved upon with reasonable effort? ...Besides using `Eigenvalues`, that is! :D

Comment: re: putting together the diagonal and subdiagonal arrays, have you seen `Riffle[]`? I seem to recall writing a bisection routine in *Mathematica* a while back; let me see if I can find it...

Comment: Also, note that [the EISPACK routine](http://netlib.org/eispack/bisect.f) possesses a number of improvements from the original *Handbook* routine; you might want to consider emulating that instead of the Algol routine from the original article.

Comment: You could use `On["Packing"]` to see if the algorithm unpacks and try to eliminate those parts of the code.

Comment: @ruebenko, I hadn't thought about that! Thanks! What's surprising, however, is that `numeig` unpacks! And it seems it's because `FoldList` unpacks! This does not look nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a starting point, here's a slight update on old code I wrote for implementing bisection:

```
n = 10;
d = Table[2 k - 1, {k, n}]; e = Table[k, {k, n - 1}]; (* Laguerre tridiagonal matrix *)

prec = 20;
(* emin and emax are bounds from Gerschgorin's theorem *)
emin = N[Min[Total /@ Partition[Riffle[d, -Abs[e]], 3, 2, {2, 1}, {}]], 3 prec/2];
emax = N[Max[Total /@ Partition[Riffle[d, Abs[e]], 3, 2, {2, 1}, {}]], 3 prec/2];

N[Table[
   a = emin; b = emax; h = Abs[b - a];
   While[h > 10^-prec,
          h /= 2; x = a + (b - a)/2; u = d[[1]] - x;
          k = Boole[Negative[u]];
          Do[
              If[u == 0, u = (e[[j]] + 10^-(2 prec)) 10^-(2 prec)];
              u = (d[[j + 1]] - Abs[e[[j]]]^2/u) - x;
              k += Boole[Negative[u]],
             {j, n - 1}];
          If[k < m, a = x, b = x];
         ];
   a + (b - a)/2,
  {m, n}], prec]
{0.1377934705404924308, 0.7294545495031704982, 1.808342901740316048,
 3.401433697854899515, 5.552496140063803633, 8.330152746764496700,
 11.843785837900065565, 16.27925783137810210, 21.996585811980761951,
 29.920697012273891560}

% == Sort[Eigenvalues[N[SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> d,
                                     Band[{2, 1}] -> e, Band[{1, 2}] -> e}], prec]]]
True
```

(Compare the eigenvalues with the output of `\[FormalX] /. NSolve[LaguerreL[n, \[FormalX]], \[FormalX], prec]` as well.)

The implementation is procedural, as you can see; it should be possible to make the code functional, but how to cleanly do so is escaping me at the moment. I'll edit this answer later if I think of something.

Comment: (P.S. I'm looking at `RecurrenceTable[]` now; maybe it can help a bit here.)